# Discord Bot But It's A User Account

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to make a bot on a discord user account so it triggers bots. How can i do this? I searched for a bit but there no results like that. Sorry for rusty english.

Comment: That is against Discord TOS and will lead to your account being suspended

Answer (score 2):

You're very vague on your question, but you are referring to a concept on Discord called "Self-bot" which is when you use different framework code to automate your Discord account to do bot like things, such as commands. This is against Discord's API [ToS](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-), and will get your account terminated without regards if caught. However, if you need help creating one anyways, please be more specific with what you're looking for, thanks!